# Translation of "When I had short hair"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, tense

I have been told that it isn't

> Wann hatte ich kurze Haare.

Is it something along the lines of

> Wann habe ich kurze Haare.

or

> Wann ich kurze Haare gehabt?

Comment: First off, "kurtze" is spelled "kurz", no T at all. "Wanna" isn't a German word either and "gehat" should be "gehabt". I fixed those. Anyway, none of your sentences is correct.

Comment: This can be answered with the help of a translator and a tool like leo.

Comment: Could you make the English phrase into a complete sentence?

Comment: @Charlie, no, it cannot, at least not reliably.

Answer (score 3):

No. If you want to say that you wish you had short hair, you should say:

> Wenn ich kurze Haare hätte, ...

If you want to say that in the past you used to have short hair, you should say:

> Als ich kurze Haare hatte, ...

*Wann* is only used when you are asking questions:

> Wann bist du in die Staaten gekommen?

Comment: Or to stick with the hair-example: Wann hatte ich kurze Haare?

Answer (score 2):

Als ich kurze Haare hatte = When I had short hair.
"Als" must be used when referring to something in the past.

(Except when making comparisons: er war kleiner als ich.)